Missing Entitlement. The bundle ... is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'."
I'm encountering an issue while trying to publish an app on TestFlight. The app in question is Home Assistant, which I've compiled from the source. I am able to compile and install the app on my device without any problems. My company's developer account is properly configured, and I have set Xcode to automatically manage the provisioning profile. The archive is also created successfully, but when I attempt to upload it to Apple Store Connect for testing via TestFlight, I receive the following error: ERROR: [ContentDelivery.Uploader] Asset validation failed (90525) Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app/PlugIns/HomeAssistant-Extensions-PushProvider.appex' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'. (ID: ceac6dcc-9c76-412e-8ea7-f2d2845f8013) I've made several attempts to resolve this issue to no avail. For instance, if I add the missing capability manually, then I am informed that the provisioning profile is incorrect. However, checking the network extension settings on my company's dev account, I see nothing related to push notifications, which are located elsewhere. Thus, I am stuck in a loop where either the provisioning file is correct but the entitlement is missing, or if the entitlement is present, then the provisioning profile is deemed incorrect.
URL:https://contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com
 status code: 409 (conflict)
    httpBody: {
  "errors" : [ {
    "id" : "ceac6dcc-9c76-412e-8ea7-f2d2845f8013",
    "status" : "409",
    "code" : "STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90525",
    "title" : "Asset validation failed",
    "detail" : "Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app/PlugIns/HomeAssistant-Extensions-PushProvider.appex' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'."
  }, {
    "id" : "9ff2143b-3c00-4912-b59f-8342fa6fe5c0",
    "status" : "409",
    "code" : "STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90525",
    "title" : "Asset validation failed",
    "detail" : "Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'."
  } ]
}
=======================================
2024-01-10 23:19:35.506 ERROR: [ContentDelivery.Uploader] Asset validation failed (90525) Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app/PlugIns/HomeAssistant-Extensions-PushProvider.appex' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'. (ID: ceac6dcc-9c76-412e-8ea7-f2d2845f8013)
2024-01-10 23:19:35.506 DEBUG: [ContentDelivery.Uploader] Error Domain=ContentDelivery Code=90525 "Asset validation failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app/PlugIns/HomeAssistant-Extensions-PushProvider.appex' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'. (ID: ceac6dcc-9c76-412e-8ea7-f2d2845f8013), NSUnderlyingError=0x6000022b6430 {Error Domain=IrisAPI Code=-19241 "Asset validation failed" UserInfo={status=409, detail=Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app/PlugIns/HomeAssistant-Extensions-PushProvider.appex' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'., id=ceac6dcc-9c76-412e-8ea7-f2d2845f8013, code=STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90525, title=Asset validation failed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app/PlugIns/HomeAssistant-Extensions-PushProvider.appex' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'., NSLocalizedDescription=Asset validation failed}}, iris-code=STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90525, NSLocalizedDescription=Asset validation failed}
2024-01-10 23:19:35.507 ERROR: [ContentDelivery.Uploader] Asset validation failed (90525) Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'. (ID: 9ff2143b-3c00-4912-b59f-8342fa6fe5c0)
2024-01-10 23:19:35.507 DEBUG: [ContentDelivery.Uploader] Error Domain=ContentDelivery Code=90525 "Asset validation failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'. (ID: 9ff2143b-3c00-4912-b59f-8342fa6fe5c0), NSUnderlyingError=0x6000022b6640 {Error Domain=IrisAPI Code=-19241 "Asset validation failed" UserInfo={status=409, detail=Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'., id=9ff2143b-3c00-4912-b59f-8342fa6fe5c0, code=STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90525, title=Asset validation failed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'., NSLocalizedDescription=Asset validation failed}}, iris-code=STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90525, NSLocalizedDescription=Asset validation failed}
2024-01-10 23:19:35.507 DEBUG: [ContentDelivery.Uploader] swinfo errors: (
    "Error Domain=ContentDelivery Code=90525 \"Asset validation failed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app/PlugIns/HomeAssistant-Extensions-PushProvider.appex' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'. (ID: ceac6dcc-9c76-412e-8ea7-f2d2845f8013), NSUnderlyingError=0x6000022b6430 {Error Domain=IrisAPI Code=-19241 \"Asset validation failed\" UserInfo={status=409, detail=Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app/PlugIns/HomeAssistant-Extensions-PushProvider.appex' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'., id=ceac6dcc-9c76-412e-8ea7-f2d2845f8013, code=STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90525, title=Asset validation failed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app/PlugIns/HomeAssistant-Extensions-PushProvider.appex' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'., NSLocalizedDescription=Asset validation failed}}, iris-code=STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90525, NSLocalizedDescription=Asset validation failed}",
    "Error Domain=ContentDelivery Code=90525 \"Asset validation failed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'. (ID: 9ff2143b-3c00-4912-b59f-8342fa6fe5c0), NSUnderlyingError=0x6000022b6640 {Error Domain=IrisAPI Code=-19241 \"Asset validation failed\" UserInfo={status=409, detail=Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'., id=9ff2143b-3c00-4912-b59f-8342fa6fe5c0, code=STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90525, title=Asset validation failed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Missing Entitlement. The bundle 'Home Assistant.app' is missing entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'., NSLocalizedDescription=Asset validation failed}}, iris-code=STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90525, NSLocalizedDescription=Asset validation failed}"
)

